# why pip is not working in cmd on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

```
C:\\Users\\HP\>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\lib\\runpy.py", line 196, in \_run_module_as_main
return \_run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\\lib\\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\\Scripts\\pip.exe_main_.py", line 4, in \<module\>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Can you tell me how to solve this issue on Windows 11?

Comment: When you were installing python, did you check "add to path"?

Comment: @BrockBrown `pip` is being ran and executed on its own. So, it's clearly on the Windows OS PATH

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hmm okay, weird. Maybe they could try reinstalling Python?

Comment: @Aditya Please stop removing the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python distribution doesn't come with pip preinstalled. Try installing pip using these methods: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

For example, on Windows, you would run

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Comment: If it "didn't come with it", then why is there a Python traceback when `pip` is ran from CMD? Clearly a `pip.exe` or `pip.bat` file exists to execute

Comment: @OneCricketeer Perhaps the way I phrased it was wrong, but either way, the pip module is not installed correctly in the Python distribution as evidenced by `No module named 'pip'`.

Comment: I agree, but any Python 3.x installation for versions released in the last 9 years have come with pip

Comment: My mistake for phrasing it wrong.

Comment: I run (py -m ensurepip --upgrade) this command and requirement already satisfied but still it can show  No module named 'pip'

Comment: @AdityaUparkar try the other options within the link. The few times I've encountered the issue, copying and running `get-pip.py` is the most reliable fix for me.

Comment: @AdityaUparkar Or, you can try to use `pipx` and `poetry` to properly install Python packages in a "virtual environment", which isolates you downloading Python libraries into your OS. https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-pipx